# How to Use Azure Active Directory Single sign on MFA authentication with dot net core web application

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication

Need a step by step Guide with Code for azure active directory login with dot net core app 
in my case azure active directory also contains MFA policy can I handle SSO with MFA in my dotnet core web app?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need this flow:

[image]

This article covers multiple scenarios:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

A few code samples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/

Comment: I've done the implementation of AD with identity provider using dot net core web app 
It was working fine until the MFA policy wasn't enabled in AD soon after MFA enabled from AD the following error is occurring even after successful sms screen and code received while it's redirecting it with the following error "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
"

Comment: Here is the code which i'm using : 
https://prnt.sc/t460pu

Comment: Am I missing something here or do I have to change the approach for AD login using MFA ?